# programing ranging data

Tags: vb.net, math, logic

I have 2 inputs from 0-180 for x and y i need to add them together and stay in the range of 180 and 0 i am having some trouble since 90 is the mid point i cant seem to keep my data in that range im doing this in vb.net but i mainly need help with the logic

Comment: Three hints.  1.  Use punctuation marks.  2.  Use Capital Letters.  3.  Post the code with **specific** questions about the code.

Comment: If these are angles and you want to represent the sum as an angle between 0 and 180, then 180-|x+y-180| should work. That is, 170+30=200, but with this formula it will be 160.

Comment: that wouldn't work because 90 is my midpoint so if at idle i have 90x and 90y i would write zero which is full reverse

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (x + y) / 2
```

Perhaps? At least that will stay in the 0-180 range. Are there any other constraints you're not telling us about, since right now this seems pretty obvious.

Comment: they are joystick positions so to go straight i would need to write 180 to left and right or to go left i would need to write 0 left and 180 right so im trying to get a vector direction right now i am taking half of each val,ue and adding them together but it is liting my top speed to 150 is there away i can add the x and y and still have fulkl range @paxdiablo @RayHidayat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *map* the two values to the limited range in a linear fashion, just add them together and divide by two:

```
out = (in1 + in2) / 2
```

If you just want to limit the top end, add them together then use the *minimimum* of that and 180:

```
out = min (180, in1 + in2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to find the average of the two or add them? If you're adding them, and you're dealing with angles which wrap around (which is what it sounds like) then, why not just add them and then modulo? Like this:

```
(in1 + in2) mod 180
```

Hopefully you're familiar with the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).